# Return value from a async method in javascript

Tags: javascript

Usually I write C#, whenever I want to return something from an asynchronous method I write the following

```
Task<List<string>> GetTop10CitiesToVisitAsync() { }
```

Using Javascript I have the possibility to mark a method with the `async` keyword. Is it possible to return an array from this method, or do I need to use a `callback function`?

Comment: use a callback function.